# How come these divs don't line up?

Tags: css, html, alignment, center

How come in this example, http://jsfiddle.net/eVdFH/ the divs don't align?

And what do I need to do in order to make them align in the center?

Theoretically for the "navigation" it should be `set to center, set width of 600px, then moved left 300px so it is in the center`

Why don't they align in the center then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be:

```
#navigation {
    margin-left: -322.5px;
}
```

Because you have `padding: 20px;` and `border: 2.5px` on that element.

Comment: Oh... Duh! Thanks a lot! I always get really confused and mixed up with padding and width and such.